# How can I retrieve and display additional text from a database when a message is clicked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, onclick, message

I want to generate a link based on the text fetched from the database. This link should have the capability to respond to an onclick event by showing another value in a text field.

The purpose of this is to display message titles, and then details pertaining to individual messages when a given message is clicked, without retrieving and transmitting the entire set of text initially.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it in a Rails way with unobtrusive Javascript, you need to do next things:

First, you need to add `jquery` and `jquery_ujs` to your application.js asset (by default this files already included in it).

Then, in the view file with messages list use link with remote option enabled `app/views/messages/index.html.erb`:

```
<%= link_to message.title, details_path(message), :remote => true %>
```

Remote links will send GET AJAX calls to your server instead of simple GET.

In the routes you need to prepare `details_path`, like this `config/routes.rb`:

```
get '/messages/:id/details' => 'messages#details'
```

Add `details` method to your `MessagesController`, `app/controllers/messages_controller.rb`:

```
class MessagesController
  def details
    @details_string = # ... take it from DB via params[:id]
  end
end
```

And at least create a view file for the new method `app/views/messages/details.js.erb`:

```
$('#details-input').val('<%= @details_string %>');
```

So when user clicks the link with message title, browser sends AJAX call to server and get Javascript something like `$('#details-input').val('Details string...');`, it runs it and you see `Details string...` in the `#details-input` text field.